# Oracle 12c installation : reference data is not available for Release "12.1" on the operating system distribution "Linux4.12.14-94.41-default

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, linux, installation, suse-linux

We are trying to install Oracle 12c in Suse Linux 12.4. As soon as we start the installation, it fails saying

```
[INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements
```

When we checked the log, we found this,

> oracle.cluster..verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: reference data is not available for Release "12.1" on the operating system distribution "Linux4.12.14-94.41-default"

We are not able to find the solution. Does this mean we cannot install 12c in our environment? Please help us to understand and fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a matter of the metadata being incomplete in the installer.

If you have access to Oracle support, then:

[Reference data is not available for release "12.1" on Linux x86-64 SLES-12 (Doc ID 2127760.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2127760.1)

In the above note, there is a link for the patch for this issue.

The workaround is to ignore the prerequisites by starting the installer as:

`./runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs`

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will try this. Hope ignoring the prerequisites will not affect anywhere. Unfortunately i do not have access to oracle support. Is it possible to get the patch from anywhere else?

Comment: My question is: why do you need to install this ancient version of Oracle ? Do you have an application that specifically requires it ? Why not 19c or 18c or air least 12.2 ?